# Vim, split window have only 1-line-size

Tags: vim

I have the problem with splitting windows. If I open a file with `:split` the size of the new window includes only one line. I don't know why.

Is there a way to resize the window in vim as I need it?

[image]

Comment: Check the value of `set winheight?` If it isn't 1, you may have a strange configuration in your vimrc.

Comment: For example, if you had `set winheight=999`, new windows would be only 1 line high until you _switch to them_, then they would grow until the previous window was 1 line.

Comment: Or you might have a strange configuration _where-ever `:verbose set winheight?` tells you_ you have a strange configuration :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jump into the window you want to resize (ctrl-w ctrl-w OR ctrl-w direction-arrow), then hit ctrl-w followed by [number followed by] + (or - if you want to decrease the size)

the number is optional and indicates how many "units" you want to enlarge the window by, defaults to 1 if not specified

Comment: +1 I'd add that you can type a number before it to specify the number of lines.

Answer (score 2):

Or just hit <kbd>^W</kbd><kbd>=</kbd> to make all windows roughly same-size.

Also, `:se mouse+=a` should enable you to just drag the dividers with the mouse, even on terminal emulators across a GNU screen session.